# How to Autowire repository interface from a different package using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and want to autowire a repository from a different package in a Rest Controller. It seems that when I place the interface and implementation in a different package the actual controller the autowire seems to fail.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.acme.repository.RawDataRepository] found for dependency:..

Controller:

```
package com.acme.controller;
import com.acme.repository.RawDataRepository;
// imports removed!

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.acme")
public class DataCollectionController {

    @Autowired
    private RawDataRepository repository;

    // code removed!
}
```

I have tried to use the @ComponentScan annotation but this gives no solution. 
Any idea what i am missing? Whenever i put the interface into the package in which the controller resides then all goes well.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have Spring Data `@Repositories` in a different package you have to explicitly `@EnableJpaRepositories` (or replace "Jpa" with your own flavour). Boot takes it's defaults from the package containing the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` so it might work to just move that class as well.

Comment: The annotation `@EnableJpaAutoConfiguration` is not available within my project but `@EnableJpaRepositories` is. Maybe this is a newer version of the same annotation!?

Comment: No, it was a typo. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use following two annotations

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "package-name")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "package-name")
```

EnableJpaRepositories will enable repository if main class is in some different package. 
You need to use EntityScan as well to point to package where you have your entity beans or else it will fail with  'Bean is not of managed type' error.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot Provides annotations for enabling Repositories.
So whenever someone uses any Repository (it can be JPARepository , CassandraReposotory) it should be enabled in Application Class itself.

**Example:**

```
@EnableCassandraRepositories("package name")
@EnableJpaRepositories("package name")
```

After providing the above annotations, the container takes care of injecting beans for repositories as well.